# How do I declare "static" classes/enums?

Tags: c++

Is there a way to force a class/enum to only be accessible in the same file, similar to how static functions/variables behave?

```
// free-floating static function
// basically I want similar access restrictions on helper-type classes/enums
static void func(void)
{
}

// this is a compiler error
static class A
{
};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A class declared inside an **Unnamed namespace** is what you want:

```
namespace
{

class SomeClass { };

}
```

This will be named mangled in such a way by the compiler that it is inaccessible outside of that translation unit.

Answer (score 7):

Just declare them within an **[Unnamed namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yct4x9k5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)**.

Note that usage of `static` to limit the scope of variables to the same *translation unit* is limited by the fact that it can be only applied to variable declarations and functions, but **not to the user-defined types**.

Unnamed namespaces remove this disadvantage and allow you to define user defined types in the scope of same translation unit.

From linked MSDN:

> Unnamed namespaces are a superior replacement for the static declaration of variables. They allow variables and functions to be visible within an entire translation unit, yet not visible externally. **Although entities in an unnamed namespace might have external linkage, they are effectively qualified by a name unique to their translation unit and therefore can never be seen from any other translation unit.**

Comment: And they work just as well as a replacement for `static` functions.